# Airflow: Pass information to next task (sensor)

Tags: python, airflow, aws-batch

*(I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574151/airflow-pass-parameters-to-dependent-task) but it's old enough I'm asking now hoping that there is an updated answer.)*

I'm writing a plugin for AWS Batch for Airflow, and after a job is submitted to Batch via the `AWSBatchOperator` operator, I need a way to wait until the job is completed and notify Airflow.  I'm writing a Sensor for that, since it seems to be the appropriate way to handle it.

However, when an `AWSBatchOperator` creates a job in AWS Batch, it needs to submit that job id to the Sensor in order for the sensor to know what job to check. Is there any simple way to pass information from a completed task to its dependent task? I know about XCom but it seemed a bit overkill given the simplicity of this situation and what I imagine to be that this is a common problem with sensors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass information from one task to the next XCOM is the only way (that i know of in Airflow). Or unless previous task writes to some external system (message queue, kafka buffer, s3 bucket etc) and the subsequent step (Sensor) checks that external value to get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the job id into a SQS queue and [trigger a AWS lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html). The lambda function can in turn [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115721/aws-lambda-and-apache-airflow-integration) the respective DAG task