# AWS Lambda and Apache Airflow integration

Tags: lambda, airflow

wondered if anyone could shed some light on this issue:

I'm trying to locate the Airflow REST API URL to initiate a DAG to Run from AWS Lambda Function.

So far from looking at all the relevant documentation provided from the Apache Incubator Site, the only guidance to solved the problem is by using this URL structure in the Lambda (python 3.6) Code:

Apache Experimental API:  https://airflow.apache.org/api.html#endpoints

based on that link the syntax should read:

```
http://airflow_hostname/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/
```

However this fails to initiate the Specific DAG in from my AWS Lambda Function, any help/guidance or pointers would be great.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_lambda_hook.py

Comment: @RicardoSaporta the question is just about the opposite, from AWS Lambda invoke a DAG run and not otherwise (from Airflow DAG invoke a AWS Lambda execution)

Comment: Could you check/provide some insights of any expected side-effects of the Lambda request to the Airflow API? (changes in the DB?) Docs mention that API is still experimental, however it should work fine.

Comment: @BenAhm I am experimenting on running airflow in aws lamba, is that something you have done. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In the Airflow 1.10 the following post request will work:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<dag_id>/dag_runs -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'    -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'
```

You need to pass an empty JSON string otherwise the post request will fail.

Comment: @benahm is this an acceptable answer? If so mark it as such so as to help guide other users (and properly credit @Jaco). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just a followup here...this post helped me as well.  The current answer mentions that a JSON string (empty or not) is required for the POST body...which is correct.  The other point which is subtle, is that the url in the OP is missing the "/dag_runs" ending portion of the url.

For clarify, here is a simple AWS lambda function that invokes an Airflow DAG named "hello_world":

```
import os
from botocore.vendored import requests
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Event Passed to Handler: " + json.dumps(event))
    data = {}
    url = 'http://ec2-11-111-11-111.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/api/experimental/dags/hello_world/dag_runs'
    print('sending POST request: ' + url)
    r = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data))
    print('response:')
    print(r)
    return r.status_code
```

Comment: If you want to pass variables from lambda to the DAG, you can use: `data = {'conf' : {'my_var': some_var, 'my_second_var': some_second_var}`. Those are subsequently available in the DAG context; to access the dictionary of your vars, you would use `kwargs['dag_run'].conf`